# Data inconsistencies between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-tables

I have an SQL question in which I am struggling to understand and find relevant resources to help me.

The question is:
"Write an SQL query to identify data inconsistencies between two tables."

I need to compare the following tables of data:

### AssetManager

| AssetManagerName |
| --- |
| John Doe |
| Joe Smith |
| Dave Grey |
| Lisa Sparks |
| Kate Green |

### Trip

| PropertyCode | AssetManagerName | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P001 | John Doe | 2022-01-22 |
| P001 | Joe Smith | 2022-01-19 |
| P002 | Dave Grey | 2022-02-25 |
| P002 | John Doe | 2022-04-23 |
| P003 | Kate Greens | 2022-02-25 |
| P004 | Joe Smith | 2022-05-29 |
| P002 | Dave Grey | 2022-01-25 |
| P001 | John Doe | 2022-02-24 |

> Image translated to text from [Original Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2PLt.png)

What are the inconsistencies in this case? Is it maybe that "Kate Green" is in the AssetManager table, and you have "Kate Green**s**" in the Trip table? That's the only thing I can see.

What MySQL commands could I use that would help me to achieve this query?

Comment: either `not exists` or `not in` maybe?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this in mind. Still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, when we talk about inconsistencies, we are generally referring to data that would not correctly translate into a normalised form, when we try to join between tables this would result in missing data or *orphaned* rows. Commonly inconsistencies arise when there is no *referential constraints* in a schema to maintain consistency. In such cases simple spelling mistakes can easily creep into the dataset, but entirely wrong values could also be used. In this case, If there is a table that represents all the possible *Asset Managers*, then we would expect that in other tables that refer to *Asset Managers* that only values from the *Asset Managers* table would be used, spelling mistakes and entirely missing names will be treated the same.

In the `Trip` Table we can identify *inconsistency* with the `AssetManager` table by looking for any records in `Trip` that do not have a match in `AssetManager` using the `AssetManagerName` column.

One simple way to do this is to use an `OUTER JOIN` and to exclude all the matches:

```
SELECT Trip.*
FROM Trip
LEFT OUTER JOIN AssetManager ON Trip.AssetManagerName = AssetManager.AssetManagerName
WHERE AssetManager.AssetManagerName IS NULL
```

This returns the following result: (See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/A8NiUwCa77ymQnH73nbrN/1))

| PropertyCode | AssetManagerName | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P003 | Kate Greens | 2022-02-25 |

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN`) will return all the rows from the `Trip` table, even if there is no corresponding match in the `AssetManager` table on the `AssetManagerName` column. For the rows that do not match, all the values for the `AssetManager` table in the result set will be `NULL`.

We can then use a `WHERE` clause to exclude all the matches data records and only return those records that *DO NOT MATCH*, we do this by only allowing where `AssetManager.AssetManagerName` has a null value.

> There are no records in `Trip` with a legitimate null value in the `AssetManagerName`, the null only exists in the recordset at a result of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` evaluation.

You could also use a `NOT EXISTS` Clause, this syntax is sometimes easier to read and identify the intent, *we want to find the records that DO NOT MATCH*. But specifically in *MySQL* it's execution plan generally less efficient than the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` expression above.

```
SELECT Trip.*
FROM Trip
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT AssetManager.AssetManagerName
    FROM AssetManager
    WHERE AssetManager.AssetManagerName = Trip.AssetManagerName
)
```

Another variation of this is to use `NOT IN`. For this query we first evaluate a list of possible values for `AssetManagerName` and use that to identify the values that do not match.

> This is helpful when there might be some legitimate null values in either of the tables for `AssetManagerName` as `IN` handles `NULL` values differently to `EXISTS`

```
SELECT Trip.*
FROM Trip
WHERE Trip.AssetManagerName NOT IN (
    SELECT AssetManager.AssetManagerName
    FROM AssetManager
)
```

For an interesting analysis of these options and performace considerations have a read over this article:
[NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: Thank you this was very informative and helped me understand the question better.